# Drop down menu with java script.changes value according to first drop down

Tags: javascript

I have two drop downs.Options in both drop downs are Male & Female.If I select Male option in one drop down it automatically changes Female in another drop down.
How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code and tell where you are facing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <select id="cat1">
<option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
   <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
<select id="cat2">
<option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
   <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$( "#cat1" ).change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Male"){
        $("#cat2").val("Female");
    } 
    if ($(this).val() == "Female"){
        $("#cat2").val("Male");
    } 
});
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgd75qhx/31/)

Comment: $( "#field_mdipxp" ).change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Male"){
        $("#field_akgi9h").val("Female");
    } 
    if ($(this).val() == "Female"){
        $("#field_akgi9h").val("Male");
    } 
});

Comment: do you have Jquery external file include in your project ?

Comment: TypeError: $ is not a function
 

$("#field_mdipxp").change(function() {

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` include this in scripts section on the top of scripts

Comment: after click on Next please select "Joint"

Comment: yes,I have applied both the codes but not working yet

Comment: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://veepal.co.in/insurance_buddy/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'></script>` is the jquery file you've added first ?.Remove this and add the one i've commented and check

Comment: #field_akgi9h do you have that id ?

Comment: But i didn't find that in the site

Comment: <select class="select_controll_837" data-size="15" style="width: 250px ! important; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;" id="field_akgi9h" name="item_meta[837]" aria-invalid="false">           <option data-content="Male" selected="selected" value="Male">        </option>        <option data-content="Female" value="Female">        </option>      </select>

Comment: Heyy,Is there any solution?

Comment: Have you changed the script ?

Comment: yes I have added this script.... 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​

Comment: Make sure you didn't added twice.Also follow the inclusion order of scripts.First add CSS(add your own css file in the last) then js files(add your own js file in the last)

Answer (score 0):

### Html and JS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dp1").change(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == "male")
          $('#dp2>option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
      else
        $('#dp2>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
      });
  $("#dp2").change(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == "male")
          $('#dp1>option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
      else
        $('#dp1>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
     <select id="dp1">
  <option value="male">male</option>
  <option value="female">female</option>
</select> 
    <select id="dp2">
  <option value="male">male</option>
  <option value="female" selected>female</option>
</select>
    </body>
```